# Yii multiply / divide with updateAll / updateCounters

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

He there!

I was wondering if there is a function in the Yii framework that allows you to multiply or divide all rows in a database. I know there is the updateAll function, that allows you to change values and updateCounters that allow you to add/subtract a number to all like this:

```
    Items::model()->updateAll(array( 'tokens' => 5 ), '' );
    Items::model()->updateCounters(array('tokens' => -5,), '');
```

But what I want to do, is multiply the value by 1.5. I tried different things, but unfortunately I cannot seem to get it work..

```
    Items::model()->updateCounters(array('tokens' => * 1.5,), '');
    Items::model()->updateAll(array( 'tokens' => 'tokens*1.5' ), '' );
```

Would be great if someone could help me find a solution.

Comment: Do you want to multiply the value that's already in the database?

Comment: He Jagsler, yeah exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the expression in [CDbExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression#__construct-detail)

```
Items::model()->updateAll(array( 'tokens' => new CDbExpression('tokens*1.5')));
```